# No iterations with scipy.optmize when trying to minimize a function

Tags: python, scipy

I'm using scipy to maximize a likelihood function by using 'minimize' from scipy.optimize to minimize the negative of the function value. I'm using the BFGS method and have written functions for the likelihood and its first derivative.

I have been able to minimize the function by estimating the gradient numerically (not providing an argument for the jacobian). However when I try to pass my gradient function as an argument, no iterations are performed to improve my initial guess of the function input values.

**EDIT:** Using check_grad from scipy I have figured out that my gradient function is flawed. This causes the line search step of the first iteration to fail so no iterations are carried out.

Here are the function and gradient:

```
def f(X):
    X = X.reshape((N,Q))
    cov = kern2.compute_noisy(X,X)
    inv_cov = np.linalg.inv(cov)
    YYt = np.dot(Y, Y.T)
    log_l = (-0.5*D*N*np.log(2*math.pi))-(0.5*D*np.log(np.linalg.det(cov))) - (0.5*np.matrix.trace(np.dot(inv_cov,YYt)))
    return -log_l

def grad(X):
    X = X.reshape(N,-1)
    cov = kern2.compute_noisy(X,X)
    inv_cov = np.linalg.inv(cov)
    YYt = np.dot(Y, Y.T)
    dlogl_dK = np.dot(np.dot(inv_cov,YYt),inv_cov) - D*inv_cov
    dK_dX = np.empty((X.shape[0], X.shape[0], X.shape[1]))
    Q = int(X.shape[1])
    for j in range(0,X.shape[0]):
        for i in range(0,X.shape[0]):
            for k in range(0,X.shape[1]):
                dK_dX[i,j,k] = (X[i][k] - X[j][k]) * kern.K(X[i,:][None],X[j,:][None])
    dK_dX = np.sum(dK_dX, axis=1)
    dlogl_dX = np.dot(dlogl_dK, dK_dX)
    return -dlogl_dX.flatten(1)
```

Checking the initial function value:

```
print f(X)
>>6597.80198798
```

Estimating the gradient numerically seems to be ok (the function is not minimized but at least something happens). X is my initial guess at the input:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
test = minimize(f, X, method='BFGS', options={'disp': True})

>>Warning: Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.
>>     Current function value: 6215.446492
>>     Iterations: 289
>>     Function evaluations: 67671
>>     Gradient evaluations: 335
```

This is what happens when I try to include the gradient function. No iterations are performed and the function value doesn't change:

```
test2 = minimize(f, X, method='BFGS', jac=grad, options={'disp': True})

>>Warning: Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.
>>     Current function value: 6597.801988
>>    Iterations: 0
>>     Function evaluations: 43
>>     Gradient evaluations: 32
```

I have looked at the documentation and can't work out why no iterations are being performed. I think I am using minimize correctly and I don't think my initial guess is at a minimum already as I have the same problem with different sets of values. Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Double check your gradient function.

Comment: Thanks pv. I have checked and it appears there is definitely something wrong with my gradient function.